# Display group aggregate and value in a column

Tags: list-view, json-formatting

Pretty simple idea, we have POs with a Number $Value and multiple invoices related to that PO each with a value. I want to show the sum invoices value(s) next to the PO value using json formatting.

Starting off with a grouped list by PO number (lookup column) and am almost immediately stuck. Because I am a newbie.

This one has some promising examples but not what I need
https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/view-samples/payments/payments-grouped.json

Comment: Can you describe more like are you using Document Library or list to store Invoice details?

Comment: I am using 2 lists, one with POs and then a lookup to the PO list in the invoice list. I'd like to group the invoice list by POS and display the PO amount somewhere, preferably close to the sum of the invoices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to enable Total for your amount field in order to get aggregate value in JSON Formatting. You can do it by following below steps

- Click On `Edit current view`

[image]

- Set your lookup column as Group By and then in Totals section select `Sum` for your column which you are using to store amount

[image]

Now apply following View formatting JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "flex-direction": "row"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "forEach": "currentValue in @aggregates",
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "inline-flex",
            "height": "25px",
            "border-radius": "15px",
            "padding-left": "8px",
            "padding-top": "5px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "forEach": "currentValue in @aggregates",
              "elmType": "div",
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.lookupValue",
              "style": {
                "display": "inline-flex",
                "height": "25px",
                "border-radius": "15px",
                "padding-right": "10px",
                "padding-top": "5px"
              }
            },
            {
              "forEach": "currentValue in @aggregates",
              "elmType": "div",
              "txtContent": "= ' - ( No. of Invoices: ' + @group.count + ')'",
              "style": {
                "display": "inline-flex",
                "height": "25px",
                "border-radius": "15px",
                "padding-right": "10px",
                "padding-top": "5px"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontWeight-bold"
              }
            },
            {
              "forEach": "currentValue in @aggregates",
              "elmType": "div",
              "txtContent": "= ' - ( Paid off: ' +  [$currentValue.value] + ')'",
              "style": {
                "display": "inline-flex",
                "height": "25px",
                "border-radius": "15px",
                "padding-right": "10px",
                "padding-top": "5px"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontWeight-bold"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It will give output as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was hoping to put the PO amount in the header and ideally the sum of the invoices too. The idea is that you can see, easily, which invoices are paid off and how much if left on them.

Comment: @SP Admin I have updated my answer. Let me know whether it does fit now in your requirement or not