# SP List group header aggregate display

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, json-formatting

Newbie here! i like to display the value of the aggregate total amount on the group header. I already have a format on my sp list. i followed this blog https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2021/03/sharepoint-list-formatting-for-grouped-views/.
i saw this question [Display group aggregate and value in a column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308446/display-group-aggregate-and-value-in-a-column) and tried to copy the code and insert to the code that i already have but i cant make it work

here is the format code i have:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "hideFooter": false,
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Accessory', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground37',if(@group.fieldData == 'Laptop', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50',if(@group.fieldData == 'Printer', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50',if(@group.fieldData == 'Smartphone', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50','sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary'))))"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Accessory', 'CoffeeScript',if(@group.fieldData == 'Laptop', 'LaptopSelected',if(@group.fieldData == 'Printer', 'PrintfaxPrinterFile',if(@group.fieldData == 'Smartphone', 'CellPhone',''))))"
          },
          "style": {
            "max-width": "24px",
            "max-height": "24px",
            "margin-top": "2px",
            "border-radius": "2px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "= '(Order Count: ' + @group.count + ')'",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.fieldData.displayValue +'(s)  ' ",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": " ",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "footerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "color": "=if(@columnAggregate.type == 'Sum' && @columnAggregate.value < 1000, '#d13438', '#107c10')",
            "font-weight": "600",
            "margin-top": "10px",
            "font-family": "Segoe UI"
          },
          "txtContent": "='Total value :' + @columnAggregate.value"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the value of the total with `@aggregates`.

Step by step:

- On the `Accessory` column header click on `Group by Accessory`
- On the `Accessory` column header click on `Totals > Count`
- On the `All Items`, click on `Format current view` and paste the JSON formatting
- Click on `Preview` + `Save` and voilà!

  ```
  {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "hideFooter": false,
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Accesory', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground37',if(@group.fieldData == 'Laptop', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50',if(@group.fieldData == 'Printer', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50',if(@group.fieldData == 'Smartphone', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50','sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary'))))"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Accesory', 'CoffeeScript',if(@group.fieldData == 'Laptop', 'LaptopSelected',if(@group.fieldData == 'Printer', 'PrintfaxPrinterFile',if(@group.fieldData == 'Smartphone', 'CellPhone',''))))"
          },
          "style": {
            "max-width": "24px",
            "max-height": "24px",
            "margin-top": "2px",
            "border-radius": "2px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "= '(Order Count: ' + @group.count + ')'",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=  @group.fieldData.displayValue +'(s)  ' ",
                  "style": {
                    "padding": " ",
                    "font-weight": "500"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }, {
              "forEach": "currentValue in @aggregates",
              "elmType": "div",
              "txtContent": "= '(Total value: ' +  [$currentValue.value] + ')'",
              "style": {
                "display": "inline-flex",
                "padding-left": "5px"
              }
            }
      ]
    },
    "footerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "color": "=if(@columnAggregate.type == 'Sum' && @columnAggregate.value < 1000, '#d13438', '#107c10')",
            "font-weight": "600",
            "margin-top": "10px",
            "font-family": "Segoe UI"
          },
          "txtContent": "='Total value: ' + @columnAggregate.value"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  }
  ```

[image: group by]
[image: total count]
[image: format current view]
[image: result]

Comment: Hello, i think my question is confusing. i already have the code and it is working. but i want to add the sum total on the group header. so the group header will display something like "(Order Count:2) Smartphone(s) Total Price: $200".

Comment: OK. I edited my answer with a new piece of code. Please accept my answer if I solved your problem.

Comment: awesome! it works! thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Can you accept and upvote my answer? Thank you.

Comment: yes! done. Thank you so much again!